# Trouble mapping custom Odata function

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, odata

I am trying to execute a custom function on an Odata webservice (in this case it is the Proof()). I am attempting to figure out what URL I need to use in order to execute this controllers Proof() method from a client. This is obviously incorrectly mapped cause I do not see the method executed when running in debug mode and making a client call (_http://localhost:53610/Receipt/AccountsReceivableWebService.Proof()).

What URL should I be using to execute this method from the client? Better yet, how can I properly map this path from the WebApiConfig? Critique is most welcome! Thanks in advance.

The webservice controller is as follows:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.OData;
using System.Web.OData.Routing;
using AccountsReceivableWebService.Models;


namespace AccountsReceivableWebService.Controllers
{
  public class ReceiptController : ODataController
{
ReceiptContext db = new ReceiptContext() { Receipt = new Receipt() { ReceiptLines = new List<ReceiptLine>() } };

private bool ReceiptExitsts(string key)
{
  return true;
}

public IHttpActionResult Get()
{


  return Ok(db.Receipt);
}

public IHttpActionResult Post(Receipt receipt)
{
  if (!ModelState.IsValid) return BadRequest(ModelState);
  if (!receipt.Insert()) BadRequest("Poorly formed receipt.");
  db.Receipt = receipt;
  return Created(db.Receipt);
}

/// <summary>
/// Checks that this receipt is a valid receipt
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>

[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult Proof()
{
  return Ok();
}


  }
}
```

The WebApiConfig.cs is where I am attempting to map the function I am wanting to execute. The code for this is below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Http;
using AccountsReceivableWebService.Models;
using System.Web.OData.Builder;
using System.Web.OData.Extensions;


namespace AccountsReceivableWebService
{
 public static class WebApiConfig
 {
  public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
  {
  // Web API configuration and services

  // Web API routes
  ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
  builder.EntitySet<Receipt>("Receipts");

  builder.Namespace = "AccountsReceivableWebService";
  builder.EntityType<Receipt>().Collection.Function("Proof").Returns<string>();


  config.MapODataServiceRoute(
    routeName: "ODataRoute",
    routePrefix: null,
    model: builder.GetEdmModel());


  }
 }
}
```

EDIT: The error I receive is 404.0 - Not Found, which leads me to believe it is a mapping issue.

Metadata:

```
<edmx:Edmx xmlns:edmx="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edmx" Version="4.0">
  <edmx:DataServices>
    <Schema xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edm" Namespace="AccountsReceivableWebService.Models">
      <EntityType Name="Receipt">
        <Key>
          <PropertyRef Name="ReceiptId"/>
        </Key>
        <Property Name="ReceiptId" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false"/>
        <Property Name="comments" Type="Edm.String"/>
        <Property Name="remitter" Type="Edm.String"/>
        <Property Name="ReceiptLineId" Type="Edm.String"/>
        <NavigationProperty Name="ReceiptLines" Type="Collection(AccountsReceivableWebService.Models.ReceiptLine)"/>
      </EntityType>
      <EntityType Name="ReceiptLine">
        <Key>
          <PropertyRef Name="ReceiptLineId"/>
        </Key>
        <Property Name="ReceiptLineId" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false"/>
        <Property Name="Comments" Type="Edm.String"/>
        <Property Name="FiscalYear" Type="Edm.String"/>
        <Property Name="CostCenter" Type="Edm.String"/>
        <Property Name="object" Type="Edm.String"/>
        <Property Name="Amount" Type="Edm.String"/>
        <Property Name="Function" Type="Edm.String"/>
      </EntityType>
    </Schema>
    <Schema xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edm" Namespace="AccountsReceivableWebService">
      <Function Name="Proof" IsBound="true">
        <Parameter Name="bindingParameter" Type="Collection(AccountsReceivableWebService.Models.Receipt)"/>
        <ReturnType Type="Edm.String" Unicode="false"/>
      </Function>
      <EntityContainer Name="Container">
        <EntitySet Name="Receipts" EntityType="AccountsReceivableWebService.Models.Receipt"/>
      </EntityContainer>
    </Schema>
  </edmx:DataServices>
</edmx:Edmx>
```

Comment: At a glance you seem to be doing everything correctly. What response do you see when you make your request? What does your $metadata look like?

Comment: My controller seems to be feeding it the wrong path (source.GetPath("AccountsReceivableWebService.Proof" + parameterString)) which equates to "Receipts/AccountsReceivableWebService.Proof()" rather than "_http://localhost:123456/Receipts/AccountsReceivableWebService.Proof()". When I enter the full address my web service is hit as expected.

Comment: I have updated the OData v4 Client Code Generator I was using to create the client (in doing so I also had to update my System.Spatial nuget package). It seems that if I use the command "container.Receipts.Proof().GetValue()" I am able to have it execute against my custom function on the server...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I use a bounded to collection function in one of my project

In WebApi.config

```
var function = customerBuilder.EntityType<MyType>().Collection.Function("MyFunction");
function.Returns<MyReturnType>();
function.Parameter<string>("myStringParameterName");
```

In my MyTypeController : ODataController

```
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult MyFunction(string myStringParameterName)
{
    //DBContextStuff
    return Ok(new MyReturnType())
}
```

This I consume data in MVC Controller

```
var myData = MyODataClient.MyType.MyFunction(myStringParameterName).GetValue();
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: From your MVC controller do you have to add the "*.GetValue()" in order for it to actually execute the function? I would have thought just the MyOdataClient.MyType.MyFunction(myStringParameterName) should be sufficient. Of course, I am still new to this framework...

Comment: The name of the function just gets the DataServiceQuery (an object with Context, RequestUri and so on) but it does not execute the http call because you can choose among sync/async/etc .. Feel free to inspect Microsoft.Odata.Client.dll